# No such file or directory for existing executable

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, executable

I just upgrade to Ubuntu 11.10 x64 from Ubuntu 11.04 32bit. But I find a really annoying problem. When I drag executable from file explorer to shell, the shell says
`bash: /home/fenfei/app/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: No such file or directory`
it's jus over there. I also have problem executing .../java. So I delete java, and extract the java package again then execute it and it works. But for `/home/fenfei/app/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb` that method doesn't work. All of them are marked as executable.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: please add the output of `ls -ahl /home/fenfei/app/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb' to your question.

Answer (score 68):

If you don't want to fill the computer up with i386 libs that you don't need.

For `adb` you just need:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

For `aapt` you need to add:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g:i386
```

You can see all the libs needed for an executable by running:

```
objdump -x .../adb | grep NEEDED
```

Some guesswork and searching is still needed to find the packages containing those files. The "Search the contents of packages" of http://packages.ubuntu.com/ is a good place to do that. Remember to add `i386` as the architecture.

Comment: Thanks, objdump helped me find missing dependencies in application I was trying to run.

Comment: Awesomely helpful.  I'm not sure how you got those libraries out of the objdump output, though.

Comment: This is the only method that worked on 13.10. I noticed that I didn't need `libncurses5:i386` though.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04. Don't forget to run `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt-get update` before

Comment: I had this same problem recently. I would never have guessed it to be a 32/64 bit incompatibility! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 41):

The message "no such file or directory" is displayed because there is a missing shared library. You can see these with the ldd command:

```
ldd /home/fenfei/app/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb
```

Probably you are missing the 32 bit libs. You have to install:

```
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

On Ubuntu 13-10, ia32-libs is no longer available; instead, install the replacement packages:

```
apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly the problem. Because android sdk doesn't have x64 version for linux. The adb works fine after installing ia32-libs

Comment: I *always* forget this after installing the SDK!

Comment: 13.10 doesn't seem to have `ia32-libs` or `ia32-libs-multiarch`

Answer (score 3):

Kenno's observations could be useful for those who like me have had ia32-libs installed:

> ```
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6-i386
> ```

http://kenno.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ubuntu-11-10-32-bit-applications-do-not-run-64-bit/