# How can I discover and install a list of dependent libraries?

Tags: installation, apt, xubuntu, dependencies

I'm trying to get the Humble Bundle version of Dungeon Defenders going, but the executable crashes with a "no such file or directory" error. Thanks to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/165536/121193) I'm able to identify the dependent libraries required:

```
$ objdump -x ./UDKGame/Binaries/DungeonDefenders-x86 | grep NEEDED
  NEEDED               libpthread.so.0
  NEEDED               libGL.so.1
  NEEDED               libSDL2-2.0.so.0
  NEEDED               libopenal.so.1
  NEEDED               libstdc++.so.6
  NEEDED               libm.so.6
  NEEDED               libgcc_s.so.1
  NEEDED               libc.so.6
  NEEDED               libdl.so.2
```

I started searching for targets with aptitude, but wondered if there's a convenient way to install all these dependent libraries, rather than manually doing them one by one?

Notes:

- Running xubuntu 12.10 64-bit.
- Other questions about fixing dependencies seem to assume that you're trying to install something with apt-get or the software manager. I just downloaded the Dungeon Defenders tar file and tried to run it.

**Edit**:

Wondering if I asked the wrong question. Maybe what I need to know is: how do you map a library name to the corresponding package/target name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the apt-file package, that gives you the reverse mapping you want.

```
apt-file search libstdc++
```

Should build the index (first time only), and result in the packages, one of which is libstdc++6.
Searching for libSDL results in only the 1.2... versions, not the 2.2 version.

Comment: Could you please elaborate for OP or be more specific?

Comment: Thanks @ubfan1. I installed apt-file, and installed all the packages that `apt-file search` identified. Almost all were already installed, except for `libstdc++6` which spat out a few errors, and `libSDL2-2.0.so.0`, which apt-file couldn't find an appropriate package. objdump still returns the same list. :(

Comment: Okay, so a friend at work suggested that it might be a problem running 32-bit app on 64-bit OS, and that I install the `ia32-libs` package, which fixed the problem. Even if it's not the solution to my specific problem, the `apt-file search` suggestion answers the question, so I've accepted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

well, in `synaptic` there is an option to do that, you check any packages that you want to install, and in file menu you choose to make a download script for those packages, I am sure that this can be done by `apt` itself too

Comment: Thanks Mostafa, I think my difficulty is that I know the library names, but don't know the corresponding package names that `apt` (and I presume `synaptic`) would need as parameters. Likewise, searching in the Software Centre for one of those libraries yields dozens of possible packages -- I have no idea which one I should choose.

Comment: You can search in synaptic for keywords