# ia32-libs broken package (Ubuntu 12.04 x64)

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, android, eclipse

I have the latest Android SDK installed on Ubuntu 12.04 x64 I am having almost an identical problem as [Problems with Eclipse and Android SDK](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147400/problems-with-eclipse-and-android-sdk). The Eclipse ADT plugin is not working for me, and its Android window shows

`SDK/build-tools/17.0.0/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

when I create a new Android project.

Then I tried

`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

but the commands fails and returns

```
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Up until now, I followed this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/165536/126730) which worked for the 32-bit `adb`, and this may have affected how Ubuntu is handling `ia-32-libs`. What must be done to correctly install the necessary libraries to get all the 32-bit Android tools to run correctly?

---

**update**

I tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/300148/126730) but it didn't work.

I tried 
`sudo apt-get purge  libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386`

but `ia32-libs` still did't install.

---

output of `ldd ./aapt`

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf778f000)
librt.so.1 => /lib32/librt.so.1 (0xf7768000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib32/libdl.so.2 (0xf7760000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib32/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7740000)
libz.so.1 => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf7658000)
libm.so.6 => /lib32/libm.so.6 (0xf7628000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7608000)
libc.so.6 => /lib32/libc.so.6 (0xf7460000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7790000)
```

`libz.so.1` is not found, and Ubuntu says that [zlib1g](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/zlib1g) is already most current.

---

Here's what worked

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch:i386

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Answer (score 6):

in Ubuntu 13.10 the ia32-libs package is no more present.

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
```

the second, shall install all its dependencies and resolve the compiling problems.
The dependencies are:

```
gcc-4.8-base:i386 libc6:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 
libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386
libgcc1:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libllvm3.3:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 
libstdc++6:i386 libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 zlib1g:i386
```

Bye,

E.

Answer (score 4):

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module`

`sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

I had this same issue. Run these commands

Comment: +1 but I've run into some issues. Please see the output at http://pastebin.com/1qefnzWX

Comment: Try something for me. Try to install ia32-libs-multiarch. It will give you another dependency error. Keep doing this until eventually it will let you install a dependency but will threaten to remove a lot of packages. Tell me that that package

Comment: That package for me was libcanberra-gtk-module. You already had that installed. You have a different missing package. Needless to say, once you find this package DO NOT INSTALL IT. Because it will remove a lot of necessary packages, just tell me what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Executing the following commands would install ia32-libs multiarch package.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch:i386
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch:i386

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch

sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution didn't work for me, what did worked was installing `libcupsfilters1:i386` before `ia32-libs`. as suggested by John in the comment #47 of [this bug on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ia32-libs/+bug/1016294?comments=all).

But I guess this workaround depends on the i386 libraries installed on the machine so the answer will be user-dependent.

Cheers.