# How can older executables be run in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 64-bit

I did a fresh install of Xubuntu 14.04. Executables like Opera Mobile Emulator no longer work. I have already tried the solutions from:

[No such file or directory for existing executable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73491/no-such-file-or-directory-for-existing-executable)

[How to run 32-bit app in Ubuntu 64-bit?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/64bit-ubuntu-14-04-running-32bit-binaries)

Though the error message is not showing up, Opera emulator does not fire up. Any help would be great.

Update:
The commands already tried are:

`dpkg --add-architecture i386`

`apt-get install ia32-libs` - doesn't work, deprecated

`apt-get install libsdl1.2debian:i386`

`apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libgcc1:i386 zlib1g:i386 libncurses5:i386`

`apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5 lib32z1`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain a bit more. Show us the command you are running, explain how you installed it, tell us if this is a fresh install of 14.04 or if you have upgraded from an older Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same rings true. You need to install what it needs. You can usually find out *what* it needs by running it in a command line and interpreting the errors and just installing the `:i386` versions of those packages.

In this case...

```
sudo apt-get install libqtgui4:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

... Should be enough.