# How to Install Opera-Mobile-Emulator on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, 32-bit, opera, emulation

I'm trying to install the [Opera-Mobile-Emulator](http://www.opera.com/developer/mobile-emulator) on the standard Ubuntu 16.04 (with all updates installed), so far with no joy. The official docs are zero help - "the emulator is *super simple* to install" (ah, not on Linux anyway).

There are some [similar questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458813/how-can-older-executables-be-run-in-ubuntu-14-04) (unfortunately for 14.04), that imply it's a matter of missing 32-bit libraries. I have tried:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libqtgui4:i386 

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqtgui4:i386 : Depends: libaudio2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.15) but it is not going to be installed
 and so on...
```

Other things that have occurred:

```
./opera-mobile-emulator-launcher
    bash: ./opera-mobile-emulator-launcher: No such file or directory
 ldd ./opera-mobile-emulator-launcher
    not a dynamic executable
```

Which is odd, given that some of the other Q&A implied that `ldd` was what they used to determine the missing requirements. (Which brings up a possibly separate question - how would I determine the requirements on 16.04?)

How can I install/launch this 32-bit package, on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I just tested the tutorial in Ubuntu 16.10 and it works without problems.

Comment: @user186255 what tutorial are you referring to? I found [this one](https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mobile-emulator/) from the help-docs in the zipfile - but that's not really what I consider a "tutorial". At least, it didn't say a word about actually _installing_ the package on Linux.